# TSX in StencilJS

Tags: stenciljs

What is the compiled version of this .tsx code, in StencilJS?

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        test
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In React is:

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    "test"
  )
 );
```

Is there an equivalent of "React.createElement" in StencilJS?

Comment: You can inspect the component.entry.js file to see the compiled version of tsx

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have to take a look at the basic "how to create a web component"
Maybe here:
https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction#how-do-i-define-a-new-html-element-

So the answer would be something like:

`class SomeElement extends HTMLElement {...}
    window.customElements.define('some-element') 
    var newElement = document.createElement('some-element')newElement.appendChild(document.createElement('div).appendChild(document.createElement('test')))`

... and so on. I guess you can get the point.

Stencil transpiles to vanillaJS which has some definitions on how to declare web components. And because they'd be awful to work with, stencil gives you a nice syntax, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can check tsconfig for JSX factory, stencil uses h() function, so basically it's the same structure but instead of React.createElement it has just h().

Answer (score 0):

first of all that method its only for rendering purpose (the component template like ReactJS).

The compiled version it is just the component with the tag you choose and that template on the DOM.

Hope this can help you, anyway you can go to [StencilJS](https://stenciljs.com/) site to read docs.

Comment: In React is:

React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    "test"
  )
);

Is there an equivalent of React object in StencilJS?

Comment: I think there is not an equivalent right now for that `createElement`